# How to style string in Angular data binding?

Tags: angular

I have variable in .ts:
`var text: string = '<strong>TEXT</strong>';`

in html have output like this:

```
<div class="text">
  <p> {{ text }} </p>
</div>
```

`<strong>` tag does not working here
Maybe there is some way to do this?

I only found one solution with [innerHtml]="text" where the tag works.

Answer (score 1):

Using `[innerHTML]` is a correct approach to render HTML tags dynamically in Angular.
But keep in mind that using `[innerHTML]` can expose your application to potential XSS attacks.
You can use `[innerHTML]` If you are sure that the HTML content is safe.
Or you can use angular `DomSanitizer` to sanitize and then prevent security vulnerabilities.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// ...

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.text = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<strong>TEXT</strong>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned that you can bind your `text` string to the paragraphs innerHTML, and this is the correct solution. Angular sanitises and strips any tags when using standard interpolation.

```html
<div class="text">
  <p [innerHTML]="text"></p> 
</div>
```

One other option is to, obviously, use CSS but this might not achieve your desired effect (having an entire paragraph bold is probably not what you are looking for)

```css
div.text > p {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You saying "Angular sanitises and strips any tags when using standard interpolation" . Standard interpolation. Maybe there is a non-standard way?

Comment: in production I receive data from the server, and wanted to use `<strong>TEXT</strong> and <italic>TEXT</italic>` in different cases

Comment: innerHTML is your friend but one thing to mention is that because you are receiving the values from the server (and cannot 100% trust the response) it would be sensible to parse it using https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Answer (score 0):

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="text">
  <p  [innerHTML]="text" > </p>
</div>
```

**TS FILE**

import { Component, OnInit, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  store = `'<strong>TEXT</strong>`;
  text: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Sanitize the HTML content
    this.text= this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.store);
  }
}
```